# como hacer una consulta con mysql y node.js

Tags: mysql, nodejs, base-de-datos, express

estoy siguiendo este tutorial;  https://medium.com/@ricardo.fanizzi/registro-login-con-node-js-express-y-mysql-backend-7eea7440837a para hacer un login con node.js , iba bien hasta que llegue a la parte de la consulta a la base de datos, estoy haciendola con POOL tal cuál como la hacen en el tutorial pero no que sucede que la consulta nunca se ejecuta, así esta mi cógido:

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');

const getAll =  () => {
 const pool = mysql.createPool ( { 
 connectionLimit : 10,
 host: process.env.DB_HOST, 
 user: process.env.DB_USER, 
 pass: process.env.DB_PASS, 
 database: process.env.DB_NAME 
 } ) ;

 //console.log('process.env.DB_HOST: ',process.env.DB_PASS);
 pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuario'), function(error,results,fields){
  console.log('todo OK-2');
  if(error) throw error;
  console.log('The solution is: ', results[0]);
  


 };
};

module.exports = { getAll: getAll }
```

fijense que tengo un console.log('todo OK-2') para saber si entra a la parte de la consulta y resulta que nunca entra, no entiendo por que. Otra cosa... en el tutorial tienen el POOL con los datos de la conexión aparte, y luego crean el users.js con la funcion que solo hace la consulta, pero me daba error, decía que db no estába definida, y es que en el users.js del tutorial nunca importa el archivo db.js, imagino que era por eso. Así que decidí tener todo en un mismo archivo, no se sería lo correcto. Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano. Saludos!

Comment: Me imagino que creaste tu archivo `.env` e instalaste el modulo `dotenv`?

Comment: Si amigo. De hecho, para probar puse un console.log antes de ejecutar la query y me imprime bien, pero el  console.log('todo OK-2');  que está dentro de la función de la query no se muestra.

Comment: Aparte de eso, te saltaste un paso en el uso de `cors` y el uso de `dotenv`, en ningún momento lo usas para la configuración de la base de datos

Comment: Yo tengo el archivo .env y dónde tengo el servidor de expréss incluyo el cors, pero el problema está aquí, es decir, la consulta a la Base de Datos no se hace, no entiendo por qué.

Comment: Coloca `require('dotenv'),config()` en tu modelo. Aunque te aconsejaría que tu configuración a la base de datos quede siempre afuera para no tenerlo que crearlo cada vez que hagas una función.

Comment: ya lo coloque, y sigue igual. En el tutorial los datos para acceder a la BD esta en un archivo aparte, pero me daba error, ya que como que ese archivo no lo incluyen en donde hacen la query, por eso lo coloque así para probar. pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Ahora me acabo de dar cuenta que no devuelves una Promesa.

Comment: y hay que hacerlo estrictamente con una promesa? es que esos conceptos aún no los manejo, se que son importantes, pero no he entendido bien lo que son observables y promesas, ando buscando algo donde lo expliquen bien.

Comment: amigo ya encontré el error, tenía esto:  pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuario'), function(error,results,fields) en vez de esto:  pool.query('SELECT * FROM usuario', function(error,results,fields) , estaba cerrando antes el paréntesis. Por casualidad sabrás de alguna página o tutorial donde enseñen con dibujitos, si es posible, lo que son observables, promesas y ese tipo de conceptos necesarios? he leído algunas páginas y aún no entiendo para que sirven ni como se usan.